# VBA: Object Variable or With Block not Set

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting

Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set.

Code:

```
If BreaksSheet.Cells(i, colS).Value <> CompleteSheet.Columns("A:A").Find(BreaksSheet.Cells(i, colS).Value) Then
```

The above code is under For loop, and code runs first time very well. But gets error on second loop.

Comment: That means the `Find` was unsuccessful. What are you trying to do? Test if the value exists on the `CompleteSheet`?

Comment: Yes I want to test if the value on breaksSheet is there in completeSheet and if not it should proceed further.... @BigBen

Comment: 'If CompleteSheet.Columns("A:A").Find(BreaksSheet.Cells(i, colS).Value) Is Nothing Then' tests if the value was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code based on the clarity in your comment on the OP.

```
Dim foundIt as Range
Set foundIt = CompleteSheet.Columns("A:A").Find(BreaksSheet.Cells(i, colS).Value) 

If foundIt Is Nothing Then
   'proceed further
End If
```